# Adding product thumbnail image to Admin catalog > Manage Products area

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml

How can I add product image thumbnail to **Catalog>Manage Categories** grid in admin (Magento 1.9.1.1)?

I have already achieved adding product image thumbnails to the Catalog>Manage Products grid via [this source](http://www.justonestepsolutions.net/2013/02/magento-admin-grid-add-custom-column-image.html). And it works perfectly.

Comment: Did you try this http://inchoo.net/magento/show-product-thumbnail-in-grids/

Comment: That was the first one I tried and it failed for me.

Answer (score -1):

If I got your question right and what you need is a special column in the Category Products grid, this is the right [solution](https://magentosolutionblog.wordpress.com/2016/04/03/add-special-column-to-category-products-grid/).

Comment: Link is broken.